# Sort 'LIKE' queries result on top and follow by other results

Tags: mysql

I want the table to sort LIKE queries result first then follow by other result. - **SOLVED**

Example:  `data = 'United States', 'New Zealand', 'South Korea'`

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE data LIKE %Korea%;
```

Output: `'South Korea'`

Expected output: `'South Korea', 'United States', 'New Zealand'`

I've researched on many places, somehow CHARINDEX its not working, neither is LOCATE (Only shows data 'South Korea').  Database Server - MySQL

Comment: This looks like a SQL query but I don't see any PHP here. If there is no revelant PHP code, even if you are using PHP to connect to the SQL database, it is best to remove that tag and also remove it from the question title.

But if you want us to engage with the PHP code (the error could be there) you will need to show us the PHP code that is generating the output. I assume you're not just typing the SQL command into a command-line tool. Also it would help for us to know which database server you're using as sometimes there are quirks specific to a given one.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've removed the tags and will update the code soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already said, it's more SQL than PHP. Then, you want all rows, so WHERE gets in the way.

One way I tested is:

```
SELECT *, INSTR(data, 'Korea') as weight
FROM table
ORDER BY weight = 0, weight;
```

This will sort first by the presence of 'Korea' in `data` (weight is zero if 'Korea' is absent), then by the position of 'Korea' in `data`.

Using [LOCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) is the same as [INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr), but the arguments are reversed:

```
SELECT data, LOCATE('Korea', data) as weight
FROM table
ORDER BY weight = 0, weight;
```

Comment: Yeah I din't know about either of those :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` is restricting what is returned.  It looks like you want it all returned but ordered in a certain way.  Not tested:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN data LIKE %Korea% THEN 1 ELSE 2
```

This might also work:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    ORDER BY IF(data LIKE %Korea%, 1, 2)
```

For both, when `data` contains `Korea` it is ordered before everything else. You could add `, data` to then order the remaining `data` ascending or descending.